# resource query call execution timing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I have code as follows :

```
    // Find a list of Adverts
    $scope.find = function() {
        debugger;
        $scope.adverts = Adverts.query();
        doSomethingWithAdverts();
    };
```

where `$scope.find()` is invoked by `data-ng-init="find()"`

As I debug through the function, when I have stepped over the `$scope.adverts = Adverts.query();`  line and hold the debugger on `doSomethingWithAdverts();` I dont see the `HTTP GET` call in firebug, only when I resume execution and exit out of this funtion.  Why is this the case, I thought `Adverts.query();` would kick off the ajax call?

This is causing incorrect behaviour when trying to use the response data in `doSomethingWithAdverts()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

anything that needs executed after the resource query has returned a response is placed in a callback function like so :

```
    // Find a list of Adverts
    $scope.find = function() {
        debugger;
        $scope.adverts = Adverts.query(function(){
           doSomethingWithAdverts();
        });

    };
```